# Migrating a classic ASP website to a new server

Tags: server, asp-classic, migrating

I'm trying to help a friend migrate a classic ASP website, as the old webhotel no longer offers classic ASP support.
There were no databases to be found on the old server.
When just copying the public_html folder to the new server, I receive an error message saying:

---

msxml3.dll error '80072ee7'

The server name or address could not be resolved

### ?, line 0

I don't have any experience working with ASP before. Can anyone give me a clue where to start looking. Attaching an image of filezilla listing the old server on the left and the new server on the right.

[file listing old server on the left, new server on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qk6L.jpg)

Technicians on the new webhotel have indicated that there seems to be a problem with the first line of the default.asp file.

Saying that the site doesn't seem to connect with this file even though it's in the folder.
The content of the db_conn.asp looks like this.

```
    <%
Dim objConn, objConn02      'Holds the Database Connection Object

Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("_db/site_db.mdb")
Set objConn02 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn02.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("_db/site_db.mdb")
%>
```

All tips and ideas gratefully received.

Comment: MSXML has nothing to do with database connections. Does default.asp contain anything like `Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")` or `Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DomDocument")`

Comment: Maybe check the file global.asa. there may be a hard coded reference to the old server IP address or some other configuration that needs changing.

Answer (score 0):

A common reason for the line 0 error is that you have the wrong or mismatched encoding on the files. I guess it is a swedish page, so open the asp file that gets the error in Notepad ++.

- Now in the encoding pull down meny check what encoding you have, probably one of ANSI, UTF-8, or UTF-8-BOM. (Im guessing utf-8-bom)
- Select all the text in the file, and copy it to the clipboard. Change the encoding to UTF-8 and paste all the code back into the file (this is because åäö) usually gets scrambled when changing encoding.
- Save the file and check if the error disappears. If you are in "luck" this worked. I say "luck" because this means that you might have to change encoding on all pages.... :/ not so "lucky" ;)

Hope it helps.